# How many integers solutions are there for the inequation: $|X_{1}|+|X_{2}|+\cdots+|X_{k}|\le n$

Tags: combinatorics

> How many solutions are there for the inequation:
>
> $$|X_{1}|+|X_{2}|+\cdots+|X_{k}|\le n$$
>   For every $i$, $X_i\in\mathbb{Z}$

**My attempt:**

I know this problem $X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots+X_{k}\le n$ $(X_i\ge0)$ is equal to $X_{1}+X_{2}+\cdots+X_{k+1}=n$. Now we have to decide for every $X_i$ whether it is $X_i$,$(-X_i)$ or zero. Therefore:

$PP_{3}^{k+1}\cdot CC_{k+1}^{n}=3^{k+1}\cdot\binom{n+k}{n}$

But It is not the correct answer.

Where is my mistake?

Comment: ugh...  This same question (in the colored quoted box) was just asked yesterday, and received several great full answers.  I'd say the _probability_ (or is it _likelihood_?) of this being on a current problem set or exam is close to 1...

Answer (score 1):

Your answer implies that you first choose a solution to $X_1+\cdots+X_{k+1}=n$ with $X_i\geq 0$, and then make one of three choices (positive, negative, or zero) for each $X_i$.

The problem here is that you can't make any choice for any $X_i$.  If $X_i=0$ in your solution, then it just is zero and no further choice can be made.  If $X_i>0$, then you can decide whether to make it positive or negative (two choices), but not zero.